# Getting independent data from multiple tables via php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get data from different tables but in one single call to server.

So far i have done this:

```
<?php

    require "con.php";

    $name = $_POST["name"];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM personnel WHERE FirstName LIKE  '%".$name."%' or MiddleName like '%".$name."%' or LastName like '%".$name."%';";


    if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        $response = array();

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            array_push($response, array("ID"=>$row[0], "FirstName"=>$row[1], "MiddleName"=>$row[2], "LastName"=>$row[3], "DOB"=>$row[4], "Nationality"=>$row[5], "Gender"=>$row[6], "Photo"=>$row[7]));
        }

        echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));
    }
    else
    {
        echo " '1";
    }
?>
```

the code works fine when data is required from just one table.........

how do i achieve multiple data abstraction thing by running this file just once.

Comment: well.. you'll have to manage it in your query. That's the best approach to my point

Comment: Are you having trouble modifying the query or does the data need to be appended from multiple queries and you're not sure how to assemble the object prior to json_encode?

Comment: Could you provide some more information, could you provide the name of the 2nd table you want to connect with your current SQL query?, I think you need to research Joins http://www.dofactory.com/sql/right-outer-join here is a example.

Comment: i have gone through joins..............but that is not required.................a separate query but all the result to be returned back to host should be in one go